# Can visual acuity be improved?

Tags: eyes, vision

Is it possible to completely cure myopia using natural methods (i.e. not with Lasik etc.)?.
I have seen websites claiming that exercising the eyes will help improve eyesight.

Is this true?

Comment: What is perfect vision?

Comment: @Kevin: 20/20 vision I guess (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart )

Answer (score 2):

While there is no such thing as perfect vision, growing evidence from Asia shows that looking often at distant objects (which one does naturally when being outside) can stop myopia progression. Vice versa, progression appears to increase when myopic children mainly live indoors.

D. J. Park, N. G. Congdon: *Evidence for an "epidemic" of myopia.* In: *Annals of the Academy of Medicine, Singapore.* 33, 1, Jan 2004, 21–26. [PMID 15008557.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15008557) (Review).

K. A. Rose, I. G. Morgan et al: *Outdoor activity reduces the prevalence of myopia in children.* In: *Ophthalmology.* 115, 8, Aug 2008, 1279–1285. DOI:10.1016/j.ophtha.2007.12.019. [PMID 18294691.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18294691)